# I can't vote to reopen a question that I closed

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-reopen

I closed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21838485/1288) after it was flagged, but a comment convinced me that the question does have enough information to be answered (it already was) and helpful to others.

When I click the reopen link, I get the following dialog.

[image: Closed dialog]

I've refreshed the page several times, but I still get the same dialog.  It seems that the page thinks I'm clicking the close link, not the reopen link.

Comment: I get the same dialog, it's not just you. Clicking *again* on the link (after dismissing the dialog) then works.

Comment: I got the message and then I tried again and it let me vote to reopen it.

Comment: Strange - a second click opens the confirmation dialog. I have now reopened the question.

Comment: Post is now re-opened. Yet that bug is weird.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-reproduced], both as a moderator and as a 3k user. This isn't related to who closed the question. If you dismiss the popup and click on “reopen” again, it works.

Answer (score 6):

I've updated the close/reopen javascript test - it now works correctly.

This will be in the next build (meta rev 2014.2.18.1962, main rev 2014.2.18.1377).